# Convert jpeg image data stored in AWS s3 to TFRecords where the sub-directory is the unique label associated with these images using AWS SageMaker

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-s3, tensorflow-datasets, amazon-sagemaker, tfrecord

I have a directory of jpeg images in AWS s3 where the sub-directory is the unique label associated with these images. I am attempting to follow this [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/f87a58cd96d45de73c9a8330a06b2ab56749a7fa/research/inception/inception/data/build_image_data.py) using AWS SageMaker and I am making a mess of input and output paths while being inexperienced with flags. Any guidance on applying the linked solution using s3 and SageMaker or another approach to achieve the output of TFRecords then saved back to s3 would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a slimmed down example that might help you. I adapted this from some code I use which includes object detection labels (multiple bounding boxes per image), so there are some TODOs added where you can tweak this for your labels. Also, not sure based on your question if an alternative is to work on the files locally. This example uses those files locally, and creates a TFRecord file that you would then upload to S3.

```
def create_tfrecords(train_img_dir, tfrecord_file):
    """ Create TFRecord file from images/labels.
            train_img_dir: A directory that contains .jpg images
            tfrecord_file: Name of a file where the tfrecords are written to
    """
    from object_detection.utils import dataset_util 
    # these same functions are available here:
    # https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord
    
    with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(tfrecord_file) as writer:
        
        #TODO: Modify this to recursivley list files in subdirs of labeled images or pull from S3
        train_img_files = [f for f in listdir(train_img_dir) if isfile(join(train_img_dir, f))]

        for i, f in enumerate(train_img_files):
            try:
                file_path = os.path.join(train_img_dir, f)
                name, ext = path.splitext(f)
                #TODO extract labe name based on path
                label = ...
                #TODO: convert the label name to an index if you want to store the index value
                label_index = ...
                
                # Skip non-jpegs
                if ext not in ['.jpg', '.jpeg']:
                    continue

                with tf.io.gfile.GFile(file_path, 'rb') as fid:
                    encoded_jpg = fid.read()
                
                # Pil image to extract h/w
                im = Image.open(file_path)
                image_w, image_h = im.size

                # Create TFRecord
                tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
                    'image/height':             dataset_util.int64_feature(image_h),
                    'image/width':              dataset_util.int64_feature(image_w),
                    'image/filename':           dataset_util.bytes_feature(f.encode('utf8')),
                    'image/encoded':            dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_jpg),
                    'image/format':             dataset_util.bytes_feature('jpeg'.encode('utf8')),
                    'image/label':              dataset_util.int64_feature(label_index),
                }))
                if tf_example:
                  writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())
            except ValueError:
                print('Invalid example, ignoring.')
                pass
            except IOError:
                print("Can't read example, ignoring.")
                pass

    print('TFRecord file created: ', tfrecord_file)
```

Then call it like this:

```
create_tfrecords(train_image_dir, tfrecord_file)
```

EDIT:
Use these methods if you don't have the object detection framework installed [source](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord):

```
# The following functions can be used to convert a value to a type compatible
# with tf.train.Example.

def _bytes_feature(value):
  """Returns a bytes_list from a string / byte."""
  if isinstance(value, type(tf.constant(0))):
    value = value.numpy() # BytesList won't unpack a string from an EagerTensor.
  return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

def _float_feature(value):
  """Returns a float_list from a float / double."""
  return tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[value]))

def _int64_feature(value):
  """Returns an int64_list from a bool / enum / int / uint."""
  return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))
```

Comment: This is extremely helpful, thank you! I am running into trouble installing object_detection.utils now.

Comment: I updated my answer with the methods and the link, which should work if you don't have the object detection framework installed.